# Tesseract giving errors

Tags: 19.04, tesseract

This morning I tried to use `tesseract` and I'm getting the following error messages:

```
$ tesseract --list-langs
Error in pixReadMemTiff: function not present
Error in pixReadMem: tiff: no pix returned
Error in pixaGenerateFontFromString: pix not made
Error in bmfCreate: font pixa not made
List of available languages (6):
eng
fra
ita
mlt
osd
spa
```

I tried `sudo apt purge tesseract*` followed by a reinstall of `tesseract-ocr` and language files, but the error message remains.

Last week, I manually installed `leptonica-1.7.8` and `jbig2-enc` libraries to use with `ocrmypdf` and everything was working fine.

Any clues on how to proceed to solve this issue?

Comment: According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33659458/tesseract-image-issue), you have to first install `libjpeg`, `libtiff`, `libpng` and then compile `leptonica`.

Comment: I had read that post, but it was not clear which packages to install. Then I found in the documentation what to install: `sudo apt install libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libwebp-dev libopenjp2-7-dev libgif-dev`. Then I recompiled leptonica and everything worked. However it still remains a mystery why I didn't have problems the first time round.

Comment: @ToDo Tiff, probably is optional. Even with some errors, tesseract-ocr was working.

Comment: It wasn't for me. No Tesseract operations where being performed.